# Restored Database is different from the original

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have recently performed a restore of our data-warehouse staging database onto a separate instance in our dev environment.   After the restore I did a comparison and it looks like the database sizes are different.  Staging_Original is 8246 MB while Staging_New is 7571.63 MB.  It appears that 2 tables in the new db are missing and for some reason the new database has a table that doesn't exist in the old database.  How is this possible if I've performed a full backup and restore?  How can I get an exact copy of one database and restore it into a second instance?  Both of the model databases appear to be the same as well.

Backup scrtip:

```
BACKUP DATABASE [BI_Staging] TO  DISK = N'G:\BI_Staging.bak' 
  WITH NOFORMAT, NOINIT,  NAME = N'BI_Staging-Full Database Backup', 
  SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10, CHECKSUM
GO
declare @backupSetId as int
select @backupSetId = position from msdb..backupset 
  where database_name=N'BI_Staging' 
  and backup_set_id=(select max(backup_set_id) 
    from msdb..backupset where database_name=N'BI_Staging' )
if @backupSetId is null 
begin 
  raiserror(N'Verify failed. Backup information for database ''BI_Staging'' not found.', 16, 1) 
end
RESTORE VERIFYONLY FROM  DISK = N'G:\BI_Staging.bak' 
  WITH FILE = @backupSetId,  NOUNLOAD,  NOREWIND
GO
```

Restore Script:

```
USE [master]
GO
ALTER DATABASE [BI_Staging] SET  RESTRICTED_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
GO

RESTORE DATABASE [BI_Staging] FROM  
DISK = N'G:\BI_Staging.bak'
WITH  FILE = 1
,  MOVE N'BI_Staging' TO N'E:\MSSQL10_50.BI_DSS2\MSSQL\DATA\BI_Staging.mdf'
,  MOVE N'BI_Staging_log' TO N'F:\MSSQL10_50.BI_DSS2\MSSQL\Tlogs\BI_Staging.ldf'
,  NOUNLOAD,  REPLACE, RECOVERY, STATS = 10
GO
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You've used `NOINIT` in your backup, and then `FILE = 1` in your restore. So it seems like you have multiple backups in the `.bak` file, and you aren't pulling the right one for the restore.  In fact you can see that in your `RESTORE VERIFYONLY` script you specify the `FILE = @backupSetId` but in the actual restore you just hard-code `FILE = 1`.

This is one of many reasons I don't like reusing a single file for multiple backups. What does it gain you? Not a whole lot, unless you are creating a gazillion backups every day and exceeding the capacity of file count by NTFS. I would much rather have a single `.bak` file with a timestamp in the name or something, then it is *very* easy to identify oldest or most current backups both visually and programmatically, restores are simpler, and it is also easier to purge expired backups.

For now, try a much simpler command with a unique filename and `WITH INIT` (I don't think you really need all of those other options)...

```
BACKUP DATABASE [BI_Staging]  
  TO DISK = N'G:\BI_Staging_This_Time_For_Sure.bak' WITH INIT;
```

...and then restore *that* file.

Comment: Thanks again for the insight Aaron.  You have once again come through for me on stackexchange!

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of completeness, you can inspect the contents of your backup file to determine the appropriate `FILE=x` parameter using the following T-SQL:

```
RESTORE HEADERONLY  FROM  
DISK = N'G:\BI_Staging.bak';
```

This will return some pertinent fields (among many others), such as:

1. `BackupStartDate` - you can use this to determine the most recent backup stored in the file.
2. `BackupTypeDescription` - this shows if the backup was a database or log backup, etc.
3. `Position` - this is the number you would use in the `RESTORE DATABASE ... FILE=x` command.

See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178536%28v=sql.110%29.aspx for further details about `RESTORE HEADERONLY`.